# Generate Entities in Symfony with two DB connections

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a project with 2 DB connections (`default` and `routeone`). My config is like this:

```
dbal:
    default_connection: routeone
    types:
        point: ACME\Infrastructure\Resources\Types\PointType

    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        routeone:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_routeone_host%"
            port:     "%database_routeone_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_routeone_name%"
            user:     "%database_routeone_user%"
            password: "%database_routeone_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
            mapping_types:
                 enum: string
                 point: point

orm:
    default_entity_manager: routeone
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                ACME:
                    type: yml
                    dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/ACME/Infrastructure/Resources/doctrine'
                    is_bundle: false
                    prefix: ACME\Domain\Entity
                    alias: ACME
        routeone:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: false
            mappings:
                RouteOne:
                    type: yml
                    dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/ACME/Infrastructure/Resources/doctrine/RouteOne'
                    is_bundle: false
                    prefix: RouteOne
                    alias: RouteOne
```

I have the control of the `default` connection, but no the `routeone`. I cannot change the structure of the existing DB in `routeone`.

When I generate the YML configuration files with this this command (NB I have put momentarily the routeone connection as a default):

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/ACME/Infrastructure/Resources/doctrine/Routeone/ --from-database`

This generate a files in this path like that: AclClass.orm.yml

```
AclClass:
    type: entity
    table: acl_class
    ....
```

But when I want to generate Entities Class with this command:

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities src/ACME/Infrastructure/Resources/doctrine/RouteOne/ --path=src/ACME/Domain/Entity/RouteOne/`

Prompt this error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
No mapping file found named 'AclClass.orm.yml' for class 'ACME\Domain\Entity\RouteOne\AclClass'.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take  look at the -em option for the doctrine commands.

Comment: I think that it's not the problem. The `doctrine:generate:entities` command don't have -em param. To avoid that, I change the default_entity_manager